# wp pagenavi not working on custom page template

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm using wp paginavi for paginating my posts, I have been able to do it so far on archive and category pages but it isn't working on my custom page template. 
I already checked the possibility of the problem being related to custom post types but found no relation. I think it might be related to the page template wordpress structure.

What is wrong with my code?

```
<?php
/* Template Name: products */

$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '') . "/../../../../";

include_once($path.'app_config.php');
include($path.'libs/meta.php');

?>
</head>

<body class="custom">


    <?php include $path . 'libs/header.php';?>



    <div class="wrap">


    <main>
        <div class="breadcrumb">
            <div class="breadcrumb-inner">
                <span><a href="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>">ホーム</a></span>
                <span>商品一覧</span>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="upper">
                <h2 class="ttl">
                    商品一覧<br>
                    <span>-  PRODUCT   -</span>
                </h2>
                <div class="navw">
                    <ul class="subnav">
                        <li><a class="pres" href="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>product/">all</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>product_gold/">golden</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo APP_URL; ?>product_tool/">gold</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="mn1">
                <div class="inner_cont">
                    <div class="content">
                        <ul class="artlist">
                            <?php
                                    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                                    $ppp = 1;

                                    $query_args = array(
                                        'paged' => $paged,
                                        // 'post_type' => array('product_gold', 'product_tool'),
                                        'post_type'=> 'post',
                                        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
                                    );


                                    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
                                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                                    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'gallery-thumb');
                                    if(empty($thumbnail)) $thumbnail = APP_URL . "images/cms/no-image.png";
                                ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>);">
                                        <img src="<?php echo APP_URL ?>images/top/mask_sp.png" alt="" class="mask">
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- .img -->
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3 class="tittle pc">
                                            <?php if( get_field('b-number') ): ?>
                                                <span class="number">No.<?php the_field('b-number'); ?></span>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 22, '...'); ?>
                                        </h3>
                                        <h3 class="tittle sp excpt">
                                            <?php if( get_field('b-number') ): ?>
                                                <span class="number">No.<?php the_field('b-number'); ?></span>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <br>
                                            <?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 18, '...'); ?>
                                        </h3>
                                        <h3 class="tittle sp ip5">
                                            <?php if( get_field('b-number') ): ?>
                                                <span class="number">No.<?php the_field('b-number'); ?></span>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <br>
                                            <?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 15, '...'); ?>
                                        </h3>

                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <?php include($path.'libs/pagination.php'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

    </main>

    <?php include($path.'libs/footer.php'); ?>

</div>

<?php include($path.'libs/scripts.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some work on the query and it did work!

```
<ul class="artlist">
                            <?php   $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                                $custom_args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                    // 'post_type' => array('product_gold', 'product_tool'),

                                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                    'paged' => $paged
                                );

                            // custom query
                            $recent_posts = new WP_Query( $custom_args );
                $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'gallery-thumb');
                if(empty($thumbnail)) $thumbnail = APP_URL . "images/cms/no-image.png";
                            // check that we have results
                            if($recent_posts->have_posts()) : ?>
                                <?php while ($recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>);">
                          <img src="<?php echo APP_URL ?>images/top/mask_sp.png" alt="" class="mask">
                        </div>
                        <!-- .img -->
                        <div class="text">
                          <h3 class="tittle pc">
                            <?php if( get_field('b-number') ): ?>
                              <span class="number">No.<?php the_field('b-number'); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 22, '...'); ?>
                          </h3>
                          <h3 class="tittle sp excpt">
                            <?php if( get_field('b-number') ): ?>
                              <span class="number">No.<?php the_field('b-number'); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <br>
                            <?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 18, '...'); ?>
                          </h3>
                          <h3 class="tittle sp ip5">
                            <?php if( get_field('b-number') ): ?>
                              <span class="number">No.<?php the_field('b-number'); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <br>
                            <?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 15, '...'); ?>
                          </h3>
                          <div class="down">
                            <div class="dd">
                              <p class="price"><?php echo the_field('a-price'); ?><?php echo the_field('b-price'); ?> 円<span class="smalls">（税別）</span></p>
                              <span class="more pc">詳細へ</span>
                              <span class="more sp">詳細を見る</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                  </ul>
                        <?php endif;
                        echo '<div class="pagination">';
                        if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $recent_posts )); }
                        echo '</div>';
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
```